# How to display all List<class> attributes in textbox?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display all objects attributes in TextBox in C#.

When I have a class with attributes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID; 
    public string name;
    public int Age;
}
```

and I have a List of objects:

```
List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();
```

filled by:

```
Person Person1 = new Person();
Person1.ID = 1;
Person1.name = "John";
Person1.Age = 20;

Person Person2 = new Person();
...
PersonList.Add(Person1);
PersonList.Add(Person2);
PersonList.Add(Person3);
```

I have to display eg. all Ages of these objects from PersonList in TextBox in short way.

I have no idea how to get Age attribute from all objects in this list and I tried:

```
this.textBox2.Text = ("Found Ages: " + string.Join(" ", PersonList));
```

but it didn't display what I need.

Maybe foreach loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use LINQ for that you want:

```
this.textBox2.Text = ("Found Ages: " + string.Join(" ", PersonList.Select(x=>x.Age));
```

**NOTE** You have to use `using System.Linq;` at the top of your source code file, if there doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 but `string.Join` accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` overload so no need to convert Age to a string

Comment: @RGraham thanks ! Isn't ok the conversion ToString for each project value?

Comment: @Dialecticus, I don't think that is needed, because the signature of string.Join is (string separator, Enumerable<string> values). So I think it's ok.

Comment: `.ToString()` would invoke the [IEnumerable<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) overload but there is no need when there is already an [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) overload

Comment: @RGraham ah I got it. Thanks ! I didn't know it.